# Is that possible to compare two strings with Z3?

Tags: z3

I'm now studying Z3 and I'm looking for a way for comparing two strings.

Is it possible to such string comparison?

Answer (score 1):

### Equality/distinctness

You can compare for equality using `=`; no other special syntax needed:

```
(= a b)
```

Note that this works uniformly for all types in SMTLib, not just strings. For negation, you can either negate the result, or use `distinct`:

```
(not (= a b))
(distinct a b)
```

The advantage of `distinct` is that it can take any number of parameters and it checks for pairwise inequality, i.e., that all the arguments are different from each other.

### Lexicographic comparisons

According to http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-UnicodeStrings.shtml, strings do support lexical comparisons via `str.<=`. Unfortunately the linked theory is still in draft form, and so far as I know neither Z3 nor any other SMT-solver (CVC4 in particular) support that operation yet.